Port scan timeout on Render while deploying C# Telegram bot using polling
I'm deploying a Telegram bot written in C# that uses polling, not webhooks, to Render. The bot is working fine locally, but when I deploy it to Render, I get the following error:
Timed out: Port scan timeout reached, no open ports detected. Bind your service to at least one port. If you don't need to receive traffic on any port, create a background worker instead.
using Application;
using Bot;
using Bot.Configurations;
using Bot.Extensions;
using Infrastructure;
using Infrastructure.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Telegram.Bot;

var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    services.Configure<BotConfiguration>(
        context.Configuration.GetSection(BotConfiguration.Configuration));

    services.AddHttpClient("telegram_bot_client")
        .AddTypedClient<ITelegramBotClient>((httpClient, sp) =>
        {
            BotConfiguration? botConfig = sp.GetConfiguration<BotConfiguration>();
            TelegramBotClientOptions options = new(botConfig.BotToken);
            return new TelegramBotClient(options, httpClient);
        });

    services.AddApplication();
    services.AddInfrastructure(context.Configuration);
    services.AddPresentation();
});

builder.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
        config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));

var host = builder.Build();

var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
try
{
    using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
    using var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    logger.LogInformation("Database was created");
    await DataSeeder.SeedDataAsync(dbContext);
    logger.LogInformation("Data was Seeded");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(ex, "Database was not created");
}

await host.RunAsync();

Changing the port: I've tried using different ports (e.g., 8080, 5000) instead of the one from the PORT environment variable, but the error persists.
Local tests: Running the bot locally works fine (with or without admin privileges), but on Render, it fails.
